Refurbishing corner cabinet lazy susan bearing
We have a kitchen corner cabinet with two lazy susan shelves (no center pole). At some point a lot of vegetable oil spilled underneath one of the shelves. The lazy susan bearing became gummed up and hard to rotate.
I disassembled the shelf. The bearing is a Triangle 12-inch lazy susan, either 12CG or 12C.
My questions are:

In this kitchen application, is the bearing typically greased, or ungreased? Because of the oil, it's very hard to tell whether it was originally greased or not. It has a race filled with many ball bearings.

What's the best way to clean it out, dry it thoroughly so it won't rust, and possibly re-grease it, if it should be greased? The whole bearing was covered with vegetable oil. I did some cleanup already with detergent and water, Goo-Gone, and WD-40 sprayed inside. I don't think I can disassemble the bearing easily.



Without actually having worked with one, I'd assume in a very low-use, low-weight application for such a large bearing, no lubricant is needed -- it would tend to attract dust. As for cleaning, mineral spirits (naphtha, charcoal lighter fluid) can be effective -- but obviously, quite flammable and should be used outdoors, in small quantity, away from source of ignition.

I soaked the bearing in dish detergent water for a couple of hours, changing the water once. Then I dried it off by hand, and baked it at 250F for about half an hour. That seemed to dry it off nicely. I applied some lithium grease to the ball bearings with a cotton swab, and spun it around. Based on the silent operation of the one I cleaned up and greased, and the other shelf, I think it was not greased.
After I posed this question, I found that the datasheet for the greased bearing had this note:

CAUTION: PROTECT BALLS AND RACES FROM SAWDUST, DIRT, PAINT, ETC.
SHOULD BEARING BECOME "ROUGH" FROM DIRTY RACES, FLUSH THOROUGHLY WITH
HOT SOAPY WATER, RINSE, OVEN DRY AND RE-OIL.

